# How to solve Django form redirect not working?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I created a form. I want to when the user fills the form and then sends it, redirect a specific page.

But in my case, the form is saving successfully but does not redirect the page. How can I solve it?

**views.py**

```
def setup_wizard(request):
    form = SetupForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            setup = form.save()
            setup.user = request.user
            setup.save()
            redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        form = SetupForm()

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'setup_wizard.html', context)
```

**dashboard.urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('', dashboard, name="dashboard"),
        path('setup', setup_wizard, name="setup"),

]
```

**mainproject.urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls')),
    ... ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using the redirect method from Django shortcuts you need to return the function result. See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.redirect) from Django docs

Comment: `return redirect('dashboard')`